# SAS aggregate rows computation

Tags: sas

I'm a beginner user of SAS especially when it comes to aggregate rows computation.

Here is a question which I believe some of you may have encountered before.

The data I have is related to insurance policies, here is an example dataset: columns from left to right are customer number, policy number, policy status, policy start date and policy cancel date (if the policy is not active, otherwise is a missing value).

```
data have;
    informat cust_id 8. pol_num $10. status $10. start_date can_date DDMMYY10.;
    input cust_id pol_num status start_date can_date;
    format start_date can_date date9.;
    datalines;
    110 P110001 Cancelled 04/12/2004 10/10/2013
    110 P110002 Active 01/03/2005 .
    123 P123001 Cancelled 21/07/1998 23/04/2013
    123 P123003 Cancelled 22/10/1987 01/11/2011
    133 P133001 Active 19/02/2001 .
    133 P133001 Active 20/02/2002 .
    ;
run;
```

Basically I want to roll these policy level information to customer level, if a customer holds at least one active policy, then his status would be 'Active', otherwise if all his policies are Cancelled, then his status becomes 'Inactive'. I also need a customer "start date" which picks up the earliest policy start date under that customer. If the customer is 'Inactive', then I need the customer's latest policy cancel date as the customer's exit date.

Below is the what I needed:

```
data want;
    informat cust_id 8. status $10. start_date exit_date DDMMYY10.;
    input cust_id status start_date exit_date;
    format start_date exit_date date9.;
    datalines;
    110 Active 01/03/2005 .
    123 Inactive 22/10/1987 23/04/2013
    133 Active 19/02/2001 .
    ;
run;
```

Solution in any form would be much appreciated! Either `DATA` step or `PROC SQL` is fine.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select cust_id,
       case when count(case when status='Active' then 1 end) > 0 
            then 'Active' 
            else 'Inactive' 
            end as status,
       min(start_date) as start_date,
       case when count(case when status='Active' then 1 end) = 0 
            then max(can_date) 
            end as exit_date
from have
group by cust_id;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attack the question in a DATA step. Here's one simple way, assuming your data are sorted by **cust_id** and **start_date**...

```
data want;
set have (keep=cust_id status start_date exit_date);

where upcase(status) contains 'ACTIVE';
by cust_id start_date;

  if first.start_date then output;
else delete;

run;

/*BEGINNER NOTES*/

*1] WHERE tells SAS to compile only records that fit a certain 
    condition - the DS 'want' will never have any observations with
    'CANCELLED' in the status variable;

*2] I use UPCASE() to standardize the contents of status, as CONTAINS
    is a case-sensitive operator; 

*3] FIRST.variable = 1 if the value is the first encountered in 
    the compile phase;
```

Comment: Assume you mean if first.start_date then OUTPUT;    Also, this does not get what the OP wants for inactive customers.